# Minimal subset of family which sum is same as sum of the family

Tags: algorithm, sum, set, time-complexity

Given family of sets calculate a sum of those sets, then point minimal (size wise) sub-family of those sets which still adds up to the sum of ALL sets. Aka remove all redundant sets in a way that leaves as few sets as possible. Sets are stored in sorted arrays. Family is twodimensional array with varying row length.

Example

```
F = {a,b,c,d,e,f}

a = {1,2,3};
b = {3,4};
c = {2,4,5};
d = {2,7,9};
e = {2,5,8};
f = {1,4,5,7};
```

sum(F) = {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9} <- notice that not every number must be in the sum, here 6 doesn't occur

examplary solution propositions:

prop. 1: {a,b,e,d} -> sums up to {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9} and nothing can be thrown away.

prop. 2: {a,b,f} -> aswell sums up to {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9} and nothing can be thrown away.

BUT: We return proposition 2 as sollution because the sub-family contains fewer sets

Provide algorithm with smallest time complexity possible

Comment: `{a,b,e,d}` makes sense. But please explain how `{a,b,f}` works, since that only seems to cover `{1,2,3,4,7}`.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put 5 in f, already corrected

Comment: What about 8 and 9?